# How to implement EMS Competing Consumers and a distributor

Tags: c#, ems

I have a Producer which sends message related to a purchase/cancel of a product on a queue and based on that i count availability of the product.

If it gets processed on multiple consumers in a wrong sequence my availability calculation will be wrong.

Now the problem is i want to get all messages related to one product being processed sequentially dispute of being processed on which consumer.

can someone suggest me how to do it.

Tools currently i am using are TIBCO EMS, C# windows services for this.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it is feasible at all to mix competing consumers AND sequence... but here are two options that might inspire you:

**Option A**

OK... I am guessing a lot of things here.

Assuming :

- You need the competing consumers for safety (ex : failure of the first one), not load sharing.
- You need all messages treated sequentially

I must make these hypothesizes, because sequence of process AND competing load sharing ARE NOT normally compatible, unless you introduce another mechanism (ex: message selectors, Topics, etc.)

All that said, you then setup the queue to be "exclusive". and have multiple clients connecting... only one will REALLY receive the messages... thus the order of processing will never be wrong. The "competing" (waiting) clients will be used only if the first one fails.

**Option B**

OK... if I was wrong above and you REALLY need multiple client to process at the same time, and still insist on the order for messages related to a specific product... try this :

Have the sending application set a JMS header with the product number in each message. Then you can setup multiple clients with message selectors tied to the new header (ex: productID=1234) on non exclusive queue (default). In that case, the clients are not really competing, but they are at least SHARING the load, and processing all messages about a product id in order. The disadvantage ? Your Message selectors must cover ALL the products IDs... not really feasible if you have thousands.

**Option C**

Similar to option C, you could separate the products into multiple queues (ex: product categories), and have ONE client for each category that process all message in order. No need for message selector on the client in that case. BUT, you need to introduce a sorting mechanism (Topic+Message Selectors, and ESB or the sender sorting himself)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for your problem could be using Sequencing Keys. You can use sequence by specifying the key values in the misc tab of the *JMS queue receiver*

[image: Sequencing Key]